# How to do flow type annotation for React Native resources?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I want to pass an image to a React Native component. What is the type of an image resource?

```js
import image from './avatar.png'

type Avatar = {
  img: ???   // what is the type of image resource?
};
const Avatar = ({ img }: Avatar) => (<Icon img={img}>)
```

Comment: It is of type `number`.

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026768/dan). You're right.

```
type Avatar = {
  img: number
};
```

In RN, we often use `require('imagepath')` as the source of an Image component. As you see below, the type `require('imagepath')` returns is a `number`. I've just tried, it works.

[image]